Generalization of a simple result in Linear Algebra
The following is trivial in case of finite dimensions for $V$: Let $V$ be a vector space over field $F$. Let $T\colon V \to W$ be a linear transformation. Then there exists a subspace $U$ of $V$ so that $U \cap \operatorname{null}(T)=\{0\}$ and $\operatorname{range}(T)=T(U)$.
We simply take a basis for the null space, extend it to the whole space's basis, and argue in the same lines of rank nullity proof.
But
Is this true in the case of arbitrary vector spaces?
I understand that assuming a basis (by virtue of Axiom of choice(AC)) would also allow us to prove this result, but can it be done without AC / Assuming basis?
One line of thought I had in mind was to use some property of $V/(\operatorname{null}(T))$, but I am not able to move ahead.

If $T:V\to W$ is a projection i.e. $T^2=T$ then we can simply take $U=null(Id-T)$. Such $U$ satisfies the required conditions. (this can be proven without AC)

@radagast but with the given information, $T^2$ needn't make sense. I'm looking to how to show this generally

@Radagast: And why are there such projections to begin with?

@AsafKaragila: Are you asking whether such projections exist or why we should consider them separately?

@Radagast: I'm asking why do these projections exist. As my answer shows, they may very well not.

@AsafKaragila: Yes of course, without hypothesis on $V$ (in infinite dimension) they could not exist, but for example if $V$ is an Hilbert space then every closed subspace of $V$ admits a topological complement, so there are at least as many projections as such closed subspaces.

The answer, of course, is no. This is not provable without using the Axiom of Choice.
Recall, or consider if this is new to you, the following fact.

Fact. The Axiom of Choice is equivalent to the following statement. For every vector space $V$ and $W\subseteq V$ there is some subspace $W'\subseteq V$ such that $W\oplus W'=V$ and $W\cap W'=\{0\}$.

So, suppose that the Axiom of Choice is false and let $V$ be a counterexample to the statement. Namely, there is some $W\subseteq V$ such that if $W+W'=V$, then $W\cap W'\neq\{0\}$.
And now consider the natural quotient map, $T\colon V\to V/W$. Then it is easy to see that $\operatorname{null}(T)=W$, but if $W'\subseteq V$ is such that $T(W')=V/W$, then for every $v\in V$, there is some $w\in W'$ such that $T(v)=T(w)$, and so $T(v)-T(w)=T(v-w)=0$ and therefore $v-w\in W$. So, $W+W'=V$, and therefore $W'\cap W\neq\{0\}$.

Sorry if it's a dumb question but how do you obtain the equivalence in your Fact.?

Not a dumb question at all. These are not trivial exercises, these are theorems that require quite a bit of understanding. https://www.impan.pl/pl/wydawnictwa/czasopisma-i-serie-wydawnicze/fundamenta-mathematicae/all/54/1/95629/some-theorems-on-vector-spaces-and-the-axiom-of-choice

+1 Nice answer! I am just a noob in linear algebra, so it took a while to parse this.
